# How to satisfy EMV standard while generating QR codes in Java?

Tags: java, qr-code, zxing, emv

I'm looking to add a QR Based payment system for my application, based in Java. I'm interested on using the EMVco based QR Standand, but I'm unsure of how to specify tags and such.

So far I have been able to encode and decode simple String and URL based QR codes using Google Zxing, but as mentioned, I'm unsure of how to work with the specific Tag IDs.

I'm a beginner in working with QR codes so thanks for all the help!

Comment: EMV QR code specification speaks about two type of implementation. Merchant providing a QR code on his device which the customer scans and initiates payment from his mobile and (2) customer mobile displaying QR code which represents the  EMV data is if it were done as a tap, which merchant scans and process as a regular EMV transaction. Which is the one you are looking at ?

Comment: As of now I am looking at the first case. I want the customer to be scanning the merchant's QR code. Requirements may change in the future, of course, but the scope is currently this.

Comment: @PranavSriram -  did you find a way to implement this..? 
if yes, could you please share the material, links or documentation that you used.